# Using the resultant request as a variable in my javascript function

Tags: javascript, npm, web-scraping

So, i'm using the NPM 'request' library to webscrape the 'URL x'. The '' content inside this 'URL x' is a single line with a youtube video link. So what I'm trying to do is: after my form is submitted, i need to verify the password to match the requirements, than redirect the user to the that youtube video link, inside the '' in the 'URL x', but I don't know how to do it, any ideas ?

```
// My JS file
var request = require('request');
var url = 'url x';

request(url, function(err, resp, body){

})

function CheckPassword(password){
  var psw = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]\w{1,6}$/;

  if (password.value.match(psw)){
    alert('Valid password, redirecting ..');
    document.location.assign(body);
    return false;
  }
  else{
    alert('Invalid password. Try again.');
    return true;
  }
}



// My form file

<form onsubmit="return CheckPassword(password)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="password-text" for="password">Password</label><br>
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required >
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="form-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `request` is a server-side module meant to be used with nodejs. The rest of your code is client-side, running in a browser. Even if this worked somehow, people can simply look at that script and go to the URL directly, bypassing the password check (which is only validation right now anyway apparently).

Comment: but thats not a problem for me right now, i just wanted to redirect to that youtube video, its possible somehow ? @ChrisG

Comment: redirection with JS is very simple: `location = url;`

Comment: The problem is that i need to use the url inside the 'url x', not simply copy the url and use it

Comment: When you say inside, do you mean scrape the url for some other url?

Comment: exactly, the link that a need to redirect is inside the 'url x'